# rails 3 authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

i'm currently buidling my own blog using rails 3. and use devise gem for authentication. the problem is , i want only one user out here --- the admin user, and prehibits others from signing up, how can I achive that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can not use [Basic Http Authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)? IMHO devise seems to be an overkill for this usecase.

Comment: oh really? what's the other one?

Comment: Basic authentication is great because its so widely supported on both the client and server side. However, allowing users to log out was a little confusing for me at first glance.